# BeaitifulSoup can't read all the namespaces

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, namespaces, xbrl

I have an XBRL document, which should be an XML document.

I am trying to extract different tags grouped by their namespace. While the code appears to work with certain namespaces (*us-gaap*), it seems to fails for other ones (*xbrli*). However, in the xml file there are plenty of tags of type * < xbrli: ... >*

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('test.xml', 'r') as fp:
    raw_text = fp.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_text, 'xml')

print( len(soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.prefix == 'us-gaap')) ) # print 941
print( len(soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.prefix == 'xbrli')) ) # print 0
```

You can find the [test.xml file here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lQz1Tfy8u7TBvatP8-QjlnzUi6rNUR79/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: I can't replicate this.I am getting both the value such as `941` and 
`1268` using your code.

Comment: pls add how expect the result output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using BeautifulSoup 4.8.1 solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this code (using CSS selectors?). Using your code I get sometimes 1268 for xbrli tags, sometimes 0 (tested on old version of `bs4==4.4.1`). Also, which version of BeautifulSoup do you use?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, __version__

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('data.txt', 'r').read(), 'xml')

print('xbrli:* tags =', len(soup.select('xbrli|*')))
print('us-gaap:* tags =', len(soup.select('us-gaap|*')))

print('Version of bs4:', __version__)
```

Prints:

```
xbrli:* tags = 1268
us-gaap:* tags = 941
Version of bs4: 4.8.1
```

Comment: Even I thought of about Css selector would be the best option.However since I couldn't reproduce after few times run I left if off.However nice thought.+1

Comment: @KunduK I've tested the OP's code on old version of bs4 `4.4.1`, and indeed, the sum of xbrli tags is (sometimes) 0. So I presume the OP is using old version of bs4.

Comment: CSS namespace selector support wasn't added until 4.7.0 with the addition of soupsieve.